# Looking for ArcGIS equivalent functions in PostGIS / Netezza / any other open source

Tags: gis, postgis, arcgis, netezza, arcpy

I am looking for the below mentioned ArcGIS Functions with the PostGIS / Netezza/ any other open source.

1. gp.Dissolve_management()
2. gp.FeatureEnvelopeToPolygon_management()
3. gp.FeatureToPoint_management()

How can I achieve same functionality in PostGIS?

Any Idea?

Thanks in advance.

Dharmesh

Answer (score 3):

For PostGis, function are not strictly equals, you will have to customize this with some SQL queries:

1. ST_Union
2. ST_Envelope
3. ST_Centroid

Comment: Thank you this will really help me. I would also like to know what would be the similar functions of gp.Select_Analysis() is just Normal select query to select the Geometry? or there is different way to perform this operation?

Comment: I would say it's just a normal SELECT. Be aware that ArcGIS and PostGIS don't have exactly the same purpose: PostGIS is more "low-level" than ArcGIS is. PostGIS only allows data manipulation in a SQL way, ArcGIS has more "user-friendly" features

Comment: Yes I understand the concern, again sorry to bother you but could you please suggest me how can I achieve "Extract Values to Points" using DB (PostGIS) Geospatial Library? I found one link here do you think is the correct way to do the Extract Values to Points in PostGIS? http://geeohspatial.blogspot.com/2013/04/testing-postgis-raster-performance.html

Comment: @htulipe I would disagree that PostGIS is more "low-level" than ArcGIS... ArcGIS provides a GUI to an ArcGIS-centric way of manipulating ArcGIS-only data. PostGIS enables spatial data management and analysis in a robust relational database (PostgreSQL)... Some would argue that SQL is a far more powerful, intuitive, and sustainable way to manage and analyze data, especially spatial data!

Comment: @Dhams I think that is the correct way - you're looking to extract raster cells to points, is that correct?

Comment: @mapBaker This is somewhat what I meant, "low-level" was not the perfect term to use here.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking at a client that will let you do these sort of activities against a post gis database I would look at Quantum GIS (also known as QGis). That way you won't need to get into writing the queries directly in PostGIS. QGis is open source and support a wide range of databases and formats including PostGIS, Shapefiles, WMS ect.

It is worth noting that Post GIS is just a database with support for GIS and does not include an editor. ArcGIS is a editor that comes with its own propriety database.

Please check it out here: http://www.qgis.org/